# Запись значения в переменную при GET запросе

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var links = [];
function get_links(album, id) {
const request = require('request-promise')
const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${album}`,
    headers: {'Authorization': `Client-ID ${id}`},
    json: true
}
request(options)
    .then(function (response) {
        response = response.data.images;

        for(let i=0; i<response.length; i++) {
         links[i] = response[i].link


       }
       console.log(links)
    })
console.log(links)
}
get_links('XXXX', 'XXXXX')
console.log(links)
```

Есть такой код для запроса к апи Imgur, как записать ответ в переменную? При создании переменной вне функции и присвоении ей значения, переменная всё равно остается пустой.

Comment: уточните и конкретизируйте вопрос, потому что `как записать ответ в переменную?` не совсем понятно, и что вы пытаетесь сделать, что у вас не получается?

Comment: @overthesanity Поправил изначальный код, а то совсем кривой скинул. Суть в том, что первый вывод в консоль сработает как положено и отобразит масив ссылок, остальные же выведут пустой массив т.е. переменную links без изменений . И я не понимаю почему так происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас запрос асинхронный, то есть вы выводите ваш массив `links`, но он еще пустой, так как не пришел ответ с `api imgur`. Для понимания почему так читаем это [асинхронность в js](https://metanit.com/web/nodejs/2.7.php)

```
const links = [];

async function getLinks(album, id) {
    const request = require('request-promise');
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${album}`,
        headers: {'Authorization': `Client-ID ${id}`},
        json: true
    };

    const response = await request(options);
    const { images } = response.data;

    for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        links[i] = images[i].link;
    }

    console.log(links);
}

getLinks('XXXX', 'XXXXX');

// console.log(links) <== здесь `links` еще `[]`
```

С вашим же примером без `async + await`:

```
const links = [];

function getLinks(album, id) {
    const request = require('request-promise');
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        uri: `https://api.imgur.com/3/album/${album}`,
        headers: {'Authorization': `Client-ID ${id}`},
        json: true
    };

    request(options).then((response) => {
        // пришел ответ с imgur
        const { images } = response.data;

        for (let i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            links[i] = images[i].link;
        }

        console.log(links); // <== а вот здесь `links` не пустой массив
    });

    // console.log(links); <== здесь `links` тоже `[]`
}

getLinks('XXXX', 'XXXXX');
```